# $\varphi(x)\sim x$ then $\psi_1(x)\sim x^2/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

The problem is from Exercise 7.11 in Stein complex analysis

> Let
> $$\varphi(x) =\sum_{p\leq x}\log p$$
> where the sum is taken over all primes $\leq x$. Prove the following are equivalent as $x\to\infty$:
> (i) $\varphi(x)\sim x,$
> (ii) $\pi(x)\sim x/\log x,$
> (iii) $\psi(x)\sim x,$
> (iv) $\psi_1(x)\sim x^2/2.$
> Here,
> $$\psi(x) = \sum_{p\leq x}\left\lfloor{\log x\over\log p}\right\rfloor\log p,\quad\psi_1(x) = \int_1^x\psi(u)\ du.$$

Textbook proved (iv)->(iii)->(ii) (Proposition 2.1, 2.2). I can prove (ii)->(i) using a similar argument. So I tried to prove (i)->(iv) using a similar method the book used to prove (iv)->(iii). Here is the proof from the textbook:

---

**Proposition $\pmb{2.2}$** *If $\psi_1(x)\sim x^2/2$ as $x\to\infty$, then $\psi(x)\sim x$ as $x\to\infty$, and therefore, $\pi(x)\sim x/\log(x)$ as $x\to\infty$.*

*Proof.* By Proposition $2.1$, if suffices to prove that $\psi(x)\sim x$ as $x\to\infty$. This will follow quite easily from the fact that if $\alpha\lt1\lt\beta$, then
$$
\frac1{(1-\alpha)x}\int_{\alpha x}^x\psi(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\le\psi(x)\le\frac1{(\beta-1)x}\int_x^{\beta x}\psi(u)\,\mathrm{d}u
$$
The proof of this double inequality is immediate and relies simply on the fact that $\psi$ is increasing. As a consequence, we find, for example, that
$$
\psi(x)\le\frac1{(\beta-1)x}[\psi_1(\beta x)-\psi_1(x)],
$$
and therefore
$$
\frac{\psi(x)}x\le\frac1{(\beta-1)}\left[\frac{\psi_1(\beta x)}{(\beta x)^2}\beta^2-\frac{\psi_1(x)}{x^2}\right].
$$
In turn this implies
$$
\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{\psi(x)}x\le\frac1{\beta-1}\left[\frac12\beta^2-\frac12\right]=\frac12(\beta+1).
$$
Since this result is true for all $\beta\gt1$, we have proved that $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\psi(x)/x\le1$. A similar argument with $\alpha\lt1$, then shows that $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\psi(x)/x\ge1$, and the proof of the proposition is complete.

---

$\varphi(x)\leq\psi(x)$ so $\int_1^x\varphi(u)\ du\leq\int_1^x\psi(u)\ du =\psi_1(x)$. So,
$${\varphi(x)\over x}\leq{1\over(\beta-1)}\left[{\psi_1(\beta x)\over(\beta x)^2}\beta^2-{\psi_1(x)\over x^2}\right].$$
But this time, $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\varphi(x)\over x} =1$ does not imply anything. I guess a completely different argument is required but can't come up with it. Please help.

Comment: I have transcribed the image to MathJax. I hope that is okay, and that I have not made any mistakes.

Comment: @robjohn Oh, thank you!

Comment: try and prove i implies iii which is fairly immediate since they don;t differ by much and then iii implies iv is a general result hat should follow by mean theorems of integrals

Comment: @Conrad That's for a continuous function, isn't it?

Comment: If $\psi(x)-x=R(x), |R(x)|=o(x)$ then $|\psi_1(x)-x^2/2+1/2|=|\int_1^x(\psi(u)-u)du| =o(x^2)$ so $|\psi_1(x)-x^2/2|=o(x^2)+1/2=o(x^2)$ and dividing by $x^2/2$ you are done!

Comment: @Conrad To conclude $|\int_1^x(\psi(u)-u)dx| = o(x^2)$ we don't need continuity of $\psi$?

Comment: Why? You apply the triangle inequality so the integral is at most $\int_1^x|R(u)|du$ and use that $R(u)=o(u)=o(x)$ for $u \le x$; if you want to give an $\epsilon$ proof you use that $|R(u )|\le c_{\epsilon}\epsilon u$ etc

Comment: @Conrad Ah only needs to care about inequality. Thank you.

Comment: happy to be of help